# iframe showing another part of the same page with another iframe inside of it

Tags: iframe

I'm using iframes inside pop-ups to show other parts of the same page (long text) that the links that trigger them are in. The problem is that if you click another such pop-up link inside that iframe, the new chosen portion of the page will take the entire iframe instead showing inside a new smaller responsive pop-up. Is there any standard workaround to this? The code is very simple:

```
<a class="internal_linkpopup" target="base" href="page1.html#internal_anchor" >xx_partofthepage</a>

<div class="modal-header">
  <span class="close">close</span>
  <center><span class="expand">expand</span></center>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <iframe frameborder="3" scrolling="yes" width="100%" style="height: 100vh;" name="base" id="ifrm">
        Your browser doesn't support iframes.
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and clean up the code snippet. It isn't displaying correctly.

Comment: thank you, this is my 1st post and I'm finding out how to escape the code

Comment: It's markdown, you escape it by indenting it by 4 spaces. There is a code icon in the editor that looks like this `{ }` which will automatically take a selected block and indent it all at once. I've cleaned it up for you in this case.

Comment: Thank you a lot!  I'm a bit surprised my code can be edited by others...  I'll have to educate my self about this network, but looks really helpful

Comment: Please do. You can follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Stack Overflow is heavily moderated to keep the quality of questions and answers high, so following that guide will help ensure your questions don't get closed for poor quality.

Comment: sounds motivating, thank you again

Comment: Include the JavaScript/jQuery of the popup please. Ideally you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, thank you all, I'll go to bed, tomorrow I'll check for already posted questions on this and read those links